# PL/SQL (Toad) auto format all database objects

Tags: oracle, git, toad

For development within our Oracle 11g database we use Toad for Oracle and Git (in TeamCoding).

One of our development rules is to use the Toad Autoformatter to have a persistent "code appearance". Since we want to change this rule set (towards less line usage), every file would be entirely in the changelog when switching from old to new formatting, making it impossible to see the actual change diff.
Also db objects would only switch to new formatting when being changed.

Is there a way to apply the Toad Formatting rules to all objects (in the database via Toad or maybe in the Git directory)? Then we could make a minor Version which only switches all objects from old to new formatting. :)

Thanks in advance!

ps: manually doing this would be possible ofc, but could take some time since we have a **lot** of objects in the database :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facing the same problem, I could not find a complete massive way; the best thing I can do is:

1. go to Schema Browser
2. select all the objects
3. do "Create script"; in "Script options" panel you'll find the format option, so you can download formatted code.
4. compile all the objects to save formatted code on DB

In this way you neeed to navigate a bit through the browser, but I hope this can help anyway.
(tested on Toad 12.1.0.22)

Comment: whew, thanks a lot! This option is hidden pretty good! I tested it with a package and it works as expected! Thanks again! =)